# In Jquery, How to prevent execution of statement until previous bunch of statements does not executes completely?

Tags: jquery

In Jquery, How to prevent execution of statement until previous bunch of statements does not executes completely.

Comment: Unless you're deliberately doing something asynchronous (ajax, setTimeout, e.g.) all statements will execute in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use callbacks :
[Callback jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Callbacks/)

You can also be a little more specific if it's not what you need

Answer (score 1):

Use as

```
$.when(function(){
     //Code for function 1 you want to execute first.
}).then(function(){
    // Code for function 2 you want to use after completion of first.
});
```